# Transformation rule on a list of non-negative integers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement

I am trying to create a transformation rule that takes a list of non-negative integer values of any length, finds a non-zero entry in the list, adds 1 to all preceding numbers, subtracts 1 from the chosen non-zero entry, and keeps the subsequent values untouched.

As an example, `{0,1,0,2,3,0}` could be transformed into `{1,0,0,2,3,0}`, `{1,2,1,1,3,0}` or `{1,2,1,3,2,0}`.

I'm looking for a transformation rule, let's call it say `desiredrule`, such that `ReplaceList[{0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0}, desiredrule]` yields those three lists above.

My (failed) attempt at this was along these lines:

```
ReplaceList[{0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0}, {x___, y_ /; y > 0, z___} -> {x + 1, y - 1, z}]
```

which results in:

```
{{1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0}, {2, 1, 3, 0}, {4, 2, 0}}
```

The key issue is obviously the `x + 1` but I'm not sure how to correct this.

I know of other ways to achieve this same result without using `ReplaceList`; I know I could, for example, do the following:

```
transform[list_] := 
 Module[{nonzeropositions, numberoftransformations}, 
  nonzeropositions = Flatten@Position[list, x_ /; x > 0]; 
  numberoftransformations = Length[nonzeropositions]; 
  Table[list[[i]] + If[i < nonzeropositions[[j]], 1, 0] + 
    If[i == nonzeropositions[[j]], -1, 0], {j, 
    numberoftransformations}, {i, Length[list]}]]
```

But I'm specifically interested to learn how I could achieve this result via the transformation rule approach I outlined initially.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ReplaceList[{0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0}, {x___, y_ /; y > 0, z___} :>  Flatten@{{x} + 1, y - 1, z}]
(*
  {{1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0}}
*)
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for.  thank you.